# Requests are pending on nodejs server after send using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending request using front end code:

```
function sendDataToApi(json, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", API_URL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
    };
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

On server side, there is a code:

```
var iterator = 0;
app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
  loop = getRandomInt(10, 30); // generate random int in range 10-30
  //execute loop and wait after 1s for a X (var loop) second
  console.log("Task id: " + iterator + " started: " + loop + "ms");
  for (i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
    console.log(" tick: " + i);
    wait(1000);
  }
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ response: iterator }));
});
```

Wait:

```
//sleep for X ms
function wait(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

I am using `var app = express();`

When I send one request, all is OK.

When I send two or more request, second, third, and next request are in state pendign and they are executed after first request is finished.

I dont know why, I am using `xhr.open("POST", API_URL, true);` thats mean true is asynchronous.

I need execute my for loop (on server side) asynchronous.

Thank you for any help.

I want simulate some log function, which takes a lot of time...

So, I need some loop, which takes some time, for example 30second server task function asynchronous to front end.

Comment: And what does `wait` do? I'm guessing it's blocking the thread, and that's why you have to wait for the first request to finish. You can't block the thread.

Comment: @adeneo I added wait function to the question.

Comment: Exactly, it's blocking. That's your problem right there, just a `setTimeout` instead of `wait` and you can do multiple requests as the thread isn't blocked.

Comment: How can I start this "loop task" in new `thread` after calling `app.post('/api'` in server from front end?

Comment: You can't, javascript is single threaded. You can however run the entire server in several threads using lots of different methods, but that's not the solution here, you should remove the blocking busy-wait function.

Comment: Lol what? I cant execute some function whitch takes for example 30 seconds? For example some hard calculation???

Comment: Nope, if that's what you want you've chosen the wrong serverside framework. Of course, anything can be done, but Node doesn't handle threads as easily as many other serverside languages, like PHP, Java, C# etc that just does it natively, Node does however do other things a lot better. In Node, whatever you do has to be **async**, otherwise you're blocking the single thread, and no other requests can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your `wait()` function is effectively blocking the thread.

Javascript is event-driven, but single threaded, meaning Node needs to have the thread freed up before it can answer another request.

When working with webservers, you should never block the thread like that, but instead create asynchronous code if you need to wait for something

```
var iterator = 0;

app.post('/api', function(req, res) {
  var loop = getRandomInt(10, 30);

  setTimeout(function() {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
      response: iterator
    }));
  }, loop * 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this serverside?:

```
app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ response: req.myUniqueRequestParam }));
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 * 1000));
});
```

Comment: Because I want simulate some log function, which takes a lot of time...

So, I need some loop, which takes some time, for example 30second asynchronous to front end.